# How can I append part of an array of characters to a string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, string-concatenation, c-strings

Suppose I have a `std::string` object and a null-terminated array of characters (or C-style string):

```
std::string str("This is a ");

const char* cstr = "strings are a really important data type.";
```

How can I append just the first N characters (in this case, 6, so that `str` will contain `This is a string`) of a C-style string to a `std::string` in the cleanest and most efficient way possible?

Comment: You won't believe it, but there's a function called `append`, i.e., `str.append(cstr, 6);`

Comment: Read some docs? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That'so dumb of me. For some reason I thought `append` was only for single chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the append method?

```
str.append(cstr, 6);
```

Comment: For completenes, you can use `cstr + n` to start from n'th (zero based) character.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `const char*` to `string` and then add it for concatenation-

```
std::string a("Hello ");  
const char* b="World!!!";  
std::string a1(b,5);  
a=a+a1;
```